# Zend Framework Form not rendering special characters like (ä, ö, ü etc) - makes the form element value empty

Tags: forms, zend-framework

I am trying to set the Zend Form working for me. I am using the same form for inserting and editing a particular database object. The object has name and I can easily create a new object with the name "Ülo". It saves correctly in database and when I fetch it to display in a report then it shows correclty "Ülo". The problem is with forms. When I open the edit form then the name element is empty. All other elements are showing correctly and if I change them to have "ü" in them they are displayed empty too. The same thing is with Form element labels. When I set a label to contain "ü" it does not show the label any more.

For example if I have `$name->setLabel('Nameü: ');` then it does not show the label but when I change it back to `$name->setLabel('Name: ');` then it shows correclty.

Same thing when I have `$bcrForm->name->setValue('Ülo');` it does not show the value but when I change it to `$bcrForm->name->setValue('Alo');` it shows correctly.

How can I fix it to display correctly? It seems like it is some kind of form rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

This one helped solving it for me:

make sure these settings are in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini:

```
default_charset = utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked encoding? Try adding this to head...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that both  your script and view files are encoded on UTF-8 and your connection to your DB is set for UTF-8 too.

If you are using mysql you force it to return UTF-8 data by openning a DB connection and running : `SET NAMES 'utf8'`

or using mysqli with : `mysqli_set_charset('utf8');`

Answer (score 0):

I would check:

- view charset
- database charset (backend)
- Zend_Db_Adapter charset
- file charset

The view escape method is set to expect utf8 chars and may strip anything else (ie. singlebyte strange chars) :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as setting escape flag to false on the elements label decorator.

```
$name->addDecorator('Label', аrray('escape'=>false));
```

Or see `setEscape()`.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html